# why Packets are not received via raw socket from all protocol using ETH_P_ALL?

Tags: go, bind, system-calls, packet, raw-sockets

```
package main
import (
"fmt"
"syscall"
)
func main() { ` 
  fd, err:= syscall.Socket(syscall.AF_PACKET, syscall.SOCK_RAW, syscall.ETH_P_ALL) //opening raw socket
  if (err != nil) {
    fmt.Println("Error: " + err.Error())
    return;
  }
  fmt.Println("Obtained fd ", fd)
  defer syscall.Close(fd)


  sa:= &syscall.SockaddrInet4{
        Addr: [4]byte{10,75,24,6}, //defining my IP
        }
    e := syscall.Bind(fd, sa)  //binding my IP
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println(e)   
         }   
   fmt.Println("Entering main loop")
    for {
        buf := make([]byte, 1024)
        numRead, err,_ := syscall.Recvfrom(fd,buf,0)   //reading the packets via raw sockets
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error")
                }
        fmt.Printf("%X\n",buf[:numRead])
    }
}`
```

I'm trying to receive packets from all protocol using `ETH_P_ALL` in raw socket.But i'm not able to receive packets.This code is written in GoLang. Can you guys please help me to sort it out

Comment: What concrete issues are you facing?

Comment: While reading from raw socket using Recvfrom() my program is struck not showing any error.while im pinging from local host im not able to receive the packets,even tried using Read() from syscall package in GO.

Comment: Will this code run? There are backticks after the opening and closing brackets in the main function.

Comment: Yes this code will run

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when you use `syscall.ETH_P_ALL` in `syscall.Socket()`, you should bind the corresponding socket address, the `syscall.SockaddrLinklayer`